# After Minimize to Tray Application Doesn't Close Properly

Tags: python, wxpython

I've been trying to minimize an application to the tray and I'm having an issue once it returns to the screen.

My Application closes properly as long as I don't minimize, Once I minimize my OnExit() does not execute.

Here is my code;

```
import wx

class simpleapp_wx(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,id,title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,title, pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( -1,-1 ))
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        Main_Frame = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL ) # Creates the Main box Sizer Parent
        self.icon = wx.Icon('MainIcon.ico', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ICO) # This gets an Icon for the application
        self.SetIcon(self.icon)  # This assigns the Icon

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.close_window) # This closes the window

        self.tbicon = wx.TaskBarIcon() # This assigns the Icon control that will be used when minimixed to tray
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_ICONIZE, self.OnIconify) # This calls the function that minimizes to tray (Iconize = Minimize)
        self.tbicon.Bind(wx.EVT_TASKBAR_LEFT_DCLICK, self.OnTaskBarActivate) # This is what return the application to the screen. TaskBar Left Double Click

        BottomButtons = wx.StdDialogButtonSizer()
        self.BottomButtonsClose = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_CLOSE, "Close" )
        BottomButtons.AddButton( self.BottomButtonsClose )
        BottomButtons.Realize();

        self.BottomButtonsClose.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.close_window) # Button click event handler

        Main_Frame.Add( BottomButtons, -1, wx.EXPAND, 5 )

        self.SetSizerAndFit(Main_Frame) # makes the Parent window size to all the items on screen
        self.Layout()

    def close_window (self, event):
        self.Destroy() # Destroy the box on close
        print "Destroy"

    def OnTaskBarActivate(self, evt): # Return from the Taskbar
        if self.IsIconized():
            print "Return to Front"
            self.Iconize(False) # Hide the icon from the Taskbar
            self.Show() # Show the Main Window
            self.Raise() #Raise the Main Window to the screen
            self.tbicon.RemoveIcon() # Remove the Icon from the Taskbar

    def OnIconify(self, evt):  
        if evt.Iconized():
            print "Minimize to Tray"
            self.Iconize(True) # Show the Icon on the Taskbar
            self.Hide() # Hide the Main Window from the screen
            self.tbicon.SetIcon(self.icon) #Set the Icon on the Taskbar
    ''' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Bottom of the Button and Control Definitions;
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'''

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        frame = simpleapp_wx(None, -1, "Minimize to Tray") # Call/assign the Main Frame
        frame.Show(True) # Show the Frame
        frame.Centre() # Center it on the screen
        return True
    def OnExit(self):
        print "OnExit Destroy0"
        self.Destroy()
        print "OnExit Destroy1"
        return False

app = MyApp(0)
app.MainLoop()
```

I've only been coding in Python/wxPython for about a month now and this is my first attempt at trying to minimize to the tray. I was happy until my application didn't close properly. I've looked at many different examples in using IsIconize and I fail to see what I am doing wrong.

Thanks for looking.

Vin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the tbicon object before you destroy the frame. It took me a while to figure this out the first time I used them too. Put something like the following into your close handler:

```
self.tbIcon.RemoveIcon()
self.tbIcon.Destroy()
self.Destroy()
```

You'll note that I remove the icon and then destroy it too. I know I had to have both back when I was doing it with 2.8, but perhaps 2.9 doesn't require the tbicon.Destroy() any longer. You'll have to play with it to see.

You can also read my tutorial on this subject if you like: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2011/12/13/wxpython-101-creating-taskbar-icons/

Comment: @ Mike Driscoll - Thank you, I had tried using the .RemoveIcon(), but didn't even think of .Destroy(). It is working fine now.